# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un programa que me diga los valores repetidos dentro de una lista y le diga dónde están los valores repetidos?

Tags: python, lista, funciones

Estoy empezando a aprender Python y tengo que hacer que este código funcione para una tarea.

Esto es lo que he hecho

```
#Presentation
print("Este programa encuentra todos los valores repetidos en una lista y le dicen en qué posición están")
print("Primero tienes que hacer una lista para eso dime")
#Entrada
elements=int(input("¿Cuántos elementos tiene esta lista? "))#Solo acepta elementos enteros
print("Dime los elementos en esta lista")
list=[]
repeated=[]
counter=0
while counter != elements:
    a=int(input("=>"))#Solo acepta enteros pero hay que hacer que pueda añadir cualquier elemento
    list.append(a)
    counter=counter+1
    
#Apartir de aquí ya insertamos una lista con n elementos y nombramos a acada elemento
    
#Ahora hay que ver si hay valores repetidos
n=0
k=0
while k != elements:
    for i in list:
        if i == list[k]:
            n=n+1
    repeated.append(k)
    print (list[k],"se repite",n,"veces")
    script=list[k]
    print(list[k],"está en la posición número",list.index(script))
    n=0       
    k=k+1
```

Investigué y sé que hay formas más fáciles de hacerlo creando un diccionario para saber cuántas veces se repite un elemento, pero todavía no puedo usarlo ya que no me han enseñado en el curso que estoy tomando.

Los únicos problemas que tengo en este momento son
-¿Cómo hacer que aparezca solo una vez cuántas veces se repite?
-¿Cómo saber en qué posición están todas las repeticiones y no solo la primera?

Aquí hay un ejemplo de lo que este programa imprime actualmente

```
Este programa encuentra todos los valores repetidos en una lista y le dicen en qué posición están
Primero tienes que hacer una lista para eso dime

¿Cuántos elementos tiene esta lista? 7
Dime los elementos en esta lista

=>3

=>5

=>4

=>5

=>5

=>2

=>3
3 se repite 2 veces
3 está en la posición número 0
5 se repite 3 veces
5 está en la posición número 1
4 se repite 1 veces
4 está en la posición número 2
5 se repite 3 veces
5 está en la posición número 1
5 se repite 3 veces
5 está en la posición número 1
2 se repite 1 veces
2 está en la posición número 5
3 se repite 2 veces
3 está en la posición número 0
```

Aunque estoy aprendiendo cosas muy básicas por ahora, si también puedes dejar una forma más optimizada y simple de resolver este problema, incluso si es más avanzado, sería muy útil, tengo curiosidad, pero también porque quiero aprender más.

Una forma de resolver este problema que me sugirió un usuario de la comunidad inglesa fue esta:

```
#Presentación
print("Este programa encuentra todos los valores repetidos dentro de una lista y te dicen en que posición están")
print("Primero hay que hacer una lista para eso dime")
#Entrada
elements=int(input("¿Cuántos elementos tiene esta lista?" ))
print("Dime los elementos de esta lista")
dicts = {}
counter=0
while counter != elements:
    a=int(input("=>"))
    dicts[counter] = a
    counter=counter+1 
  
rev_dict = {} 
for key, value in dicts.items(): 
    rev_dict.setdefault(value, set()).add(key) 
  
  
result = filter(lambda x: len(x)>1, rev_dict.values())
for x in result:
    print(str(dicts[next(iter(x))]),"se encuentra en las posiciones",str(x))
```

Se puede completar para que diga cuantas veces se repiten y no solo en que posiciones se encuentran los valores si se repiten, de cualquier modo de encontrar una solución que no incluya utilizar diccionarios sería de mucha ayuda y muy satisfactorio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se me ocurre el siguiente algoritmo. No te doy el código, sino el pseudocódigo, para que intentes implementarlo tú mismo, ya que es un ejercicio de clase y no es misión de este sitio resolver problemas académicos.

Voy a suponer que está permitido modificar la lista que estamos comprobando (si no fuera así, se debería crear antes una copia y trabajar con la copia). La idea es ir poniendo un `None` en las posiciones de los elementos que ya hayamos visto como repetidos, para no volver a procesarlos.

Entonces iterando por los índices de la lista, si el contenido asociado a ese índice es `None`, lo ignoramos y vamos al siguiente. Si es distinto de `None`, entonces para los restantes índices (desde ese en adelante) comparamos lo que hay en ellos con lo que hay en el índice actual. Si son iguales, ponemos a `None` los encontrados y metemos a una lista auxiliar los índices de los elementos repetidos. Esta lista auxiliar se inicializaría en cada iteración del bucle principal, antes de entrar al bucle anidado que verifica el resto de índices.

Al salir del bucle anidado, si la lista auxiliar tiene más de un elemento, es que hemos encontrado repetidos. La longitud de la lista auxiliar nos dirá cuántos repetidos hay y los contenidos de esa lista nos darán los índices en que se encontraron las repeticiones.

En pseudocódigo, más o menos, sería así:

```
para cada índice i en la lista:
   si el elemento i-ésimo es None, no se hace nada
   inicializar lista auxiliar con el índice i
   para cada índice desde i+1 hasta el final
      si el elemento i-ésimo es igual al j-ésimo
         poner a None el j-esimo
         añadir j a la lista auxiliar
   si la lista auxiliar tiene más de 1 elemento
      mostrar que el elemento iésimo se repite
      mostrando lo almacenado en la lista auxiliar
```

## Usando un diccionario

Podríamos tener un diccionario cuyas claves sean los datos que encontramos en la lista y tengan como valores asociados otras listas, que serán los índices en que aparece ese dato.

Un diccionario así se podría crear con un bucle como el siguiente:

```
repeticiones = {}  # diccionario inicialmente vacio
for i in range(len(lista)):
   if lista[i] not in repeticiones:  # Si la clave aún no existía
      repeticiones[lista[i]] = []   # la creamos con una lista vacía
   # Ahora añadimos a esa lista el índice i que acabamos de encontrar
   repeticiones[lista[i]].append(i)
```

Por ejemplo, si la lista contiene `[3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 3]`, el diccionario que acabamos de crear al final contendrá:

```
{3: [0, 6], 5: [1, 3, 4], 4: [2], 2: [5]}
```

Ahora ya podríamos recorrer este diccionario para mostrar qué elementos aparecen más de una vez, con algo como:

```
for numero, indices in repeticiones.items():
    if len(indices)>1:
        print(f"{numero} se repite {len(indices)} veces, en {indices}")
```

y esto mostraría:

```
3 se repite 2 veces, en [0, 6]
5 se repite 3 veces, en [1, 3, 4]
```

### Más avanzado

Aunque la idea en esta parte es la misma que la recién mostrada, la sintaxis puede mejorarse para que el código sea más compacto y fácil de leer, si hacemos uso de:

- `defaultdict(list)` que es un diccionario que crea automáticamente en su interior elementos de tipo lista (vacía) si intentamos acceder a una clave que no existía en el diccionario. Así podemos hacer directamente `diccionario[clave].append(valor)` y si el elemento ya existía, se añadirá el valor a la lista y si no existía se creará una lista vacía a la que se añadirá ese valor.
- `enumerate(lista)` permite obtener parejas de valores `(indice, numero)` evitando así tener que iterar por los índices y luego tener que poner `lista[i]`.

Con estas mejoras, la creación del diccionario sería así:

```
from collections import defaultdict
repeticiones = defaultdict(list)
for i, n in enumerate(lista):
    repeticiones[n].append(i)
```

La forma de mostrar el diccionario sería la misma de antes.

Comment: Wow que respuesta más completa. Voy a seguir tu consejo! :D

Answer (score 1):

Logré resolverlo y les comparto lo que aprendí

- Si está buscando encontrar la posición de valores repetidos en una lista usando list.index
  solo le dirá dónde está el primer elemento, no todos.
- El uso de funciones es muy útil para trabajos complejos (quizás este no sea el mejor ejemplo) y le ayuda a dar un mejor orden a lo que hace, por lo que se recomienda acostumbrarse a usar estas funciones, ya que también le brinda la oportunidad de El usuario puede generar sus propias variables.
- Tomar descansos es bueno, le ayuda a descansar y le da la oportunidad de pensar mejor sobre las soluciones que está buscando y cómo simplificar los problemas que quería resolver de una manera compleja.
- stack **overflow** es un buen recurso para aprender cosas nuevas y encontrar diferentes soluciones de lo que pensabas

Aquí está el código

```
#Función
def buscar_repetidos(lista,valor):
    posición=[]
    indice=0

    for elemento in lista:
        if elemento == valor:
            posición.append(indice)
        indice +=1
    return posición

#Presentación
print("Este programa encuentra todos los valores repetidos dentro de una lista y te dicen en que posición están")
print("Primero hay que hacer una lista para eso dime")

#Entrada
while True:
    try:
        elementos=int(input("¿Cuántos elementos tiene esta lista? "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Por favor escribe la cantidad de elementos con caracteres numéricos y enteros")

print("Dime los elementos de esta lista. Pueden ser de cualquier tipo")
lista=[]
contador=0
while contador != elementos:
    valor=input("-> ")
    lista.append(valor)
    contador += 1
#Apartir de aquí ya insertamos una lista con n elementos y nombramos a acada elemento

#Ahora hay que ver si hay valores repetidos
unicos = []
k=0
while k != elementos:
    elemento=lista[k]
    posición=buscar_repetidos(lista,elemento)
    if elemento not in unicos:
        if len(posición)==1:
            print (elemento,"se repite",len(posición),"vez en la posición",posición)
        else:
            print (elemento,"se repite",len(posición),"veces en las posiciones",posición)
        unicos.append(elemento)
    k += 1
```

Y este es un ejemplo de lo que imprime

```
Este programa encuentra todos los valores repetidos dentro de una lista y te dicen en que posición están
Primero hay que hacer una lista para eso dime

¿Cuántos elementos tiene esta lista? 7
Dime los elementos de esta lista. Pueden ser de cualquier tipo

-> &

-> 2.7

-> 4

-> a

-> 2.7

-> &

-> a
& se repite 2 veces en las posiciones [0, 5]
2.7 se repite 2 veces en las posiciones [1, 4]
4 se repite 1 vez en la posición [2]
a se repite 2 veces en las posiciones [3, 6]
```